# Unofficial Skyrim Patch: Wearing a hooded robe and a dragon priest mask at the same time

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When I do not have the [Unofficial Skyrim Patch](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/19) installed, I can wear the [Archmage's Robes](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Archmage's_Robes) and [Morokei](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Morokei_(Mask)) at the same time (which is not a bug/glitch, it's intentional).

After installing the Unofficial Skyrim Patch, this combination is no longer possible. If I equip the one and then the other, the first gets unequipped like they are not compatible.

I can only guess the authors of the mod introduced this change as a reaction to [this Skyrim bug](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Archmage's_Robes#Bugs):

> *[PC] [360]* While wearing [the robes](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Archmage's_Robes), [Dragon Priest masks](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Priest_Mask) (such as [Morokei](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Morokei_(Mask)) and the [Wooden Mask](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Wooden_Mask)) might make the player's head invisible, to solve this, drop the robes and pick them up, or unequip the mask.

How can I make this combination possible without having to give up on the fixes introduced by the Unofficial Skyrim Patch?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on information from [UESP on Archemage's Robes](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Archmage's_Robes), the version of the robes you got are "hooded" and isn't suppose to be worn with a headgear (see Bugs section in UESP).

However, there is a second version that is non-hooded and is available in the Archmage's quarters.  The Unofficial patch corrects this version and allows you to wear it along with Morokei.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I was able to find the robe laying on a table. Note that the "un-hooded" version of the robe does not have the original +50 Magicka boost.

Comment: Since that hood doesn't cover your face, I would draw issue with the idea that that's a bug. Oh well. Write a letter to the patch makers, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

I think the [**USSEP - Archmage Robes - Mask and Circlet re-enable patch**](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/3700/) mod will help you. It re-enables wearing circlets and masks with the hooded Archmage's Robes.

If you want this effect for all hoods, then you should use the [**Circlets or Masks with all Robes and Hoods**](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/3732) mod instead.

Just load it after the USSEP.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the hooded robe with the mask on. Just simply turn off the Unofficial Patch , go back to your game and wear the robe and mask together, save the file.Then turn on the Unofficial patch again. Once you check your stats , the +50 Magicka will still be there but when you undress robe the additional Magicka will be removed though, but no worries you can just repeat the process again to regain the effect.

Answer (score -2):

I haven't tried this but you may be able to glitch the two together.
Their is a glitch that makes it so you can where to armors at the same time. Go to a jail and make sure you're follower is their with you.
Tell them to wait in the jail sell. Commit a crime, go to jail and put the mask on. When you get out you should respawn with the mask and the hooded robes on at once. Hope this helped.